# How to replicate MySQL's aes-256-cbc in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, aes

Using [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/replicating-mysql-aes-encryption-methods-with-php/) article as a guide I was able to successfully replicate MySQL's aes-128-ecb in PHP:

```
final class Encryption
{

  // The key
  const KEY = '36F3D40A7A41A827968BE75A87D60950';

  /**
   * Encrypt a string
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function encrypt($string)
  {
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::getMySQLKey(self::KEY), self::getPaddedString($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
  }

  /**
   * Decrypt a string
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function decrypt($string)
  {
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::getMySQLKey(self::KEY), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), "\x00..\x10");
  }

  /**
   * Get MySQL key
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $key
   * @return string
   */
  public static function getMySQLKey($key)
  {

    // The new key
    $new_key = str_repeat(chr(0), 16);

    // Iterate over the key and XOR
    for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($key); $i < $l; ++$i)
    {
      $new_key[$i % 16] = $new_key[$i % 16] ^ $key[$i];
    }

    // Return the new key
    return $new_key;

  }

  /**
   * Get padded string
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function getPaddedString($string)
  {
    return str_pad($string, (16 * (floor(strlen($string) / 16) + 1)), chr(16 - (strlen($string) % 16)));
  }

}
```

As an example:

```
// PHP, gives CJI+zJyviQI7GgSCLGMNsqsXq2MDKC3a9FIG3wDrE8Y=
base64_encode(Encryption::encrypt('michael@example.com'))

// MySQL, gives CJI+zJyviQI7GgSCLGMNsqsXq2MDKC3a9FIG3wDrE8Y=
SELECT TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('michael@example.com', '36F3D40A7A41A827968BE75A87D60950'));
```

However, I want to update to using aes-256-cbc but am having difficulties. I started by replacing `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` with `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` and `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB` with `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC` and used the `KEY` constant as the initialization vector:

```
  /**
   * Encrypt a string
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function encrypt($string)
  {
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, self::getMySQLKey(self::KEY), self::getPaddedString($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, self::KEY);
  }

  /**
   * Decrypt a string
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function decrypt($string)
  {
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, self::getMySQLKey(self::KEY), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, self::KEY), "\x00..\x10");
  }
```

The problem is that I'm now getting different values from PHP and MySQL:

```
// PHP, gives XSRfnrl05CE7JIHCvfhq6D67O0mAW2ayrFv2YkjFVYI=
base64_encode(Encryption::encrypt('michael@example.com'))

// MySQL, gives lTLT4MRXcHnOAsYjlwUX4WVPHgYvyi6nKC4/3us/VF4=
SELECT TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('michael@example.com', '36F3D40A7A41A827968BE75A87D60950', '36F3D40A7A41A827968BE75A87D60950'));
```

I'm unsure where to proceed from here so any help would be appreciated.

And just to confirm that MySQL is indeed using the correct encryption method:

```
// aes-256-cbc
SELECT @@session.block_encryption_mode
```

Comment: You've gone from a key length of 128 bits (16 bytes) to 256 bits (32 bytes) but have retained the constant 16 in your code.

Comment: Sorry, which bit are you referring to? The `KEY` constant? I doubled it up  (but used the first 32 for the IV), but that hasn't helped.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the three times that the number `16` appears in your `getMySQLKey` function.

Comment: Changing that gives `gQc6iL6rdagUsUtMRs+rSZO/00LnakwGS5LcjUugdyU=` which is still different to what MySQL gives.

Comment: And you're also using the revised, 256-bit, keys (in both MySQL and PHP)?

Comment: Yes. With `EB648D0BFCA30CADC75634B10C5A3A341F8BDC268069CA2F2EB79D3BF8D58D00` as the key PHP gives `yv+yTTgMAeENBkG7OHXca4gHNHcDy3JINcMSRE5uyXQ=` and MySQL gives `Q59X8/wAqeeweRx+FUiUNPJtIPG04PAmCiW946eU3P4=`.

Comment: AES-256 is still `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` and not `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`. AES and Rijndael are not synonymous. AES-256 is selected by providing a 32 byte key to `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`.

Comment: Yes, you and eggyal have solved it. Switch back to `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, change `16` to `32` in `getMySQLKey`, and then use a 16 byte IV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As neither [eggyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623041/eggyal) nor [Artjom B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816580/artjom-b) have chosen to provide an answer with their solution, I'll do so on their behalf.

The first issue is that AES-256 still uses `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` rather than `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`, and the second is that AES-256 is used over AES-128 by providing a 32 byte key rather than a 16 byte key.

The below provides a correct implementation:

```
final class AESEncrypter
{

  // The key
  const KEY = 'F40E2A9E22150793C6D0CA9E316FEA42';

  // The IV
  const IV = '5C354934224F698E';

  /**
   * Encrypt a string
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function encrypt($string)
  {
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::getMySQLKey(self::KEY), self::getPaddedString($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, self::IV);
  }

  /**
   * Decrypt a string
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function decrypt($string)
  {
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, self::getMySQLKey(self::KEY), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, self::IV), "\x00..\x10");
  }

  /**
   * Get MySQL key
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $key
   * @return string
   */
  public static function getMySQLKey($key)
  {

    // The new key
    $new_key = str_repeat(chr(0), 32);

    // Iterate over the key and XOR
    for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($key); $i < $l; ++$i)
    {
        $new_key[$i % 32] = $new_key[$i % 32] ^ $key[$i];
    }

    // Return the new key
    return $new_key;

  }

  /**
   * Get padded string
   *
   * @access public
   * @static
   * @param string $string
   * @return string
   */
  public static function getPaddedString($string)
  {
    return str_pad($string, (16 * (floor(strlen($string) / 16) + 1)), chr(16 - (strlen($string) % 16)));
  }

}
```

As an example:

```
// PHP, gives mwVraDh/7jG3BvPJyYqgxY6Ca8CTRN5JHvwPGeV8Vd0=
base64_encode(AESEncrypter::encrypt('michael@example.com'))

// MySQL, gives mwVraDh/7jG3BvPJyYqgxY6Ca8CTRN5JHvwPGeV8Vd0=
SELECT TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT('michael@example.com', 'F40E2A9E22150793C6D0CA9E316FEA42', '5C354934224F698E'))
```

Answer (score 1):

AES is a subset of Rijndael so to use it for AES one must select a block size of 128-bits and a key size of 128, 192 or 256 bits.

MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 specifies a block size of 256-bits, not the key size, similarly MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 specifies a block size of 128-bits, not the key size. This is a common confusion.

This implementation of Rijndael auto selects a key size based on the passed key so it is important to use a key of exactly the correct desired size.

Also note that the iv length is the same as the block size so for AES it is 128-bits in length.

This is a good example of how poor naming can have unfortunate consequences.